# Multithreaded code in Java with ExecutorService fails to return, why?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have very similar multithreaded code elsewhere in my codebase that works fine, but I can't see quite what's going wrong here.

This is a simple multi-threaded process to generate some result XML for a search query. The output of running this method is:

> Returning from threads

The line System.out.println("Finished multithreading loop");" is never reached.

Modifying the number of threads doesn't help.

```
private void fillAllResults() {
        int threads = 2;
        final FutureTask[] tasks = new FutureTask[threads];
        final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for (int i = 0; i < allResults.size(); i++) {
            tasks[i] = new FutureTask<Integer>(new Callable<Integer>() {
                public Integer call() throws Exception {
                    int index;
                    while ((index = getResultsIndex()) < allResults.size()) {
                        System.out.println("Processing result " + index);

                        Result result = allResults.get(index);
                        fillResultXML(result);
                    }
                    System.out.println("Returning from threads");
                    return 1;
                }
            });
            executor.execute(tasks[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
            try {
                tasks[i].get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        executor.shutdown();

        System.out.println("Finished multithreading loop");
    }
```

Edit, thanks all for the quick replies! Here's the answers:

It shows 'processing result' as many times as I have results. If allResults.size() is 25, it shows processing result 1, processing result 2 ... processing result 24.

Here's the extra code that's missing:

```
private List<Result> allResults = new ArrayList<Result>();
private int resultsIndex = 0;

private synchronized int getResultsIndex() {
return resultsIndex++;
}
```

And in case anyone's wondering, I can guarantee that none of the code within the loop increases the size of allResults.

Comment: Does it show "Processing result" multiple times? What happens if you break in with the debugger?

Comment: Runs the while loop forever? What does `index = getResultsIndex()` do? Maybe it returns an index from zero to size-1 and thus the loop is never left?

Comment: Also, please show the declaration of `allResults` and the implementation of `getResultsIndex()`.  If you're not seeing any output then you have a deadlock.

Comment: I've answered by editing the original post - I don't think it's an infinite loop but I could be wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This probably isn't the cause but resultsIndex should probably be volatile if other threads should see the latest value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it is related to the fact, that your array `tasks` has a length of `threads` (i.e. two in your case) but you assign more values to it within the lines

```
for (int i = 0; i < allResults.size(); i++) {
    tasks[i] = ...
    ....
}
```

If your list `allResults` has more than two entries your thread will be stopped by an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Maybe you catch this one but do not handle it properly outside the code you presented.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like getResultsIndex() isn't updating after every loop resulting in an infinite loop.

Comment: @Ina: what happens when you test for this?

Comment: I've edited the original post to show getResultsIndex(). I don't see why getResultsIndex() wouldn't update, it's synchronized and counts to infinity (or at least, to Integer.MAX_VALUE, but that's still bigger than allResults.size()).

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your code what allResults and getResultsIndex are, but you never seem to update whatever getResultsIndex returns.